# Swapping ContentPresenter content in custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have 2 ContentPresenter `fixedContentPresenter` and `resizableContentPresenter` and obviously a Content in Generic.xaml. How can i set the Content to be **only** in `fixedContentPresenter` when `FixedContent = true;` and Content to be **only** in `resizableContentPresenter` when `FixedContent = false;`

I tried changing the content in the code but the content is not showing.
Xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="fixedContent"/>
    <Grid>
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="resizableContent"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Could you show us the code you tried?

Comment: You can use ContentControls and bind their Content properties appropriately. If this is all in a ControlTemplate or DataTemplate, you can have triggers at the template level to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an implicit style on the content presenters to either hide or show a specific presenter depending on the value of `FixedContent`

```
<Style TargetType={x:Type ContentPresenter } x:Key="HideOrShow">
   <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FixedContent}" Value="False">
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
      </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: The trigger thing is interesting, showing or hiding is now what i want, i need to swap the content between the 2 contentpresenter... how about through code

Comment: @HishamMaudarbocus If you show the same content in both, and one is visible while the other is not, that has the same effect as swapping. In WPF, that's probably the most common way to produce a "swapping" effect.

Comment: is resource usage same if we use your recommended scenario?

Comment: @HishamMaudarbocus You will need to determine if the resource usage is disadvantageous, but for most situations it should be fine.

Comment: @OmegaMan i modified you answer a bit and it worked, however am a bit worried about the resource usage. What happens if the content is control that uses heavy animation, will it be rendered twice because it is present in both content presenters?

Comment: @HishamMaudarbocus, I am unfamiliar with animation controls when hidden, you will need to verify; but that is a good thought.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ContentControl` here instead of `ContentPresenter`.

When `FixedContent` values changes, `Content` becomes null, so no `Animation` related side-effects.

```
 <Grid Background="Purple">

    <ContentControl x:Name="fixedContent" Margin="0,75,0,0">
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FixedContent, Mode=OneWay}" Value="false">
                        <DataTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource ContentKey}"/>                               
                        </DataTrigger.Setters>
                    </DataTrigger>                        
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>

    <Grid Background="Red" Margin="0,54,0,0">
        <ContentControl x:Name="resizableContent" Margin="0,75,0,0">
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FixedContent, Mode=OneWay}" Value="true">
                            <DataTrigger.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource ContentKey}"/>
                            </DataTrigger.Setters>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I like your answer, I think it speaks to resource allocation issues as you mention, but I believe you have the logic  to handle `FixedContent` boolean's reversed. Not in this order false / true, but true / false.

Answer (score 0):

After a day of struggle, I finally found a better answer than that proposed by @OmegaMan, let's hope it help others. Here's the new XAML (added `Content="{x:Null}"` to both `ContentPresenter`):

```
<Grid>
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="fixedContent" Content="{x:Null}"/>
    <Grid>
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="resizableContent" Content="{x:Null}"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And the `FixedContent` logic:

```
public bool FixedContent
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(FixedContentProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(FixedContentProperty, value);
        if (value) // Is Fixed
        {
            ResizableContentPresenter.Content = null;
            FixedContentPresenter.Content = Content;
        }
        else
        {
            FixedContentPresenter.Content = null;
            ResizableContentPresenter.Content = Content;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Outright wrong !!! See my answer. First of all you should not use `ContentPresenter` here, Secondly you should not put any kind of code in setters. What if you want to take more action when this property's value changes ? Better would be to make use `PropertyChangedCallback`, but accessing any `Control` from there would be bad too.

Comment: i'll give your answer a try once i get back to my computer, anyway i dont think a static resource will fit here, the content may change at anytime

Comment: Things depend upon actual scenarios, you didnt mention this in your question.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with putting code in getters or setters. I have done that on 100% of all C# projects I have ever worked on. Now whether to use `PropertyChangedCallback` is a different matter.

Comment: @OmegaMan anyway thats a bad practice.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan I disagree, it speaks to why the language designers put in properties in the first place. Otherwise if it is truly a bad practice, why not keep with field variables instead? Using specialized getter and setter operations with targeted operations is a cornerstone of Object Oriented design. I will agree that any paradigm can be taken to far and abused; sure. But used properly it is a great design feature.

Comment: @OmegaMan I am talking about DP and not CLR props.

Comment: i kindda agree with both of you, @OmegaMan is right with the properties and but if we fillow MVVM pattern, we can minimize logic code by using the method proposed by AnjumSKhan